# htaccess rewrite url is causing error with og metatags

Tags: .htaccess, meta-tags

My church website has og meta tags for the description and images and all that jazz. They have all been working fine.
Recently they asked me to remove the .php extensions from the url, so I used htaccess to achieve that. All the rewriting seemed to be working fine using this.

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# Make all requests have the www. in them
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ourchurch\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ourchurch.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

## don't touch /my_admin_controls URIs
RewriteRule ^my_admin_controls/ - [L,NC]

## don't touch /ourScheduler URIs
RewriteRule ^ourScheduler/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

Now, for some reason the facebook og tags are not working properly.
I looked in the debugger and it said there was a redirect error.

Anyone have any ideas where I went wrong?

...edit...
sample of the og

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ourchurch.com/images/fblogo.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Fall Retreat"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ourchurch.com/fall_retreat.php"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Our church .....etc etc"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Come for fellowship...etc etc."/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<title>Retreat Registration</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Could you give a snippet of the head section of one of your pages. i.e between `<head>` tag that contains the meta tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because you use redirect in your `.htaccess` to remove the extension, i.e The **R** flag, try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

In addition, from your meta tags code you have:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ourchurch.com/fall_retreat.php"/>
```

which should be:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ourchurch.com/fall_retreat"/>
```

Because you already make a redirect to remove the `.php` then the Facebook suffers from redirect loop and it could not able to reach the page.

**Refrences**:

- http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: that makes sense.. I will try just removing that from the og and see if I need to further edit my htaccess

Comment: You were correct in just removing the .php in the og tag. Thank you. Just for further information, should I start removing the .php from all internal links to cut down on the number of redirects from htaccess? or just leave the a tags as they are?

Comment: What do you mean by internal links? If you mean something like links in your website pages that links to another pages, it is better to do that too, beside changing the regarded `og url`.

Comment: yep, I was just referencing my links to other pages in the navigation areas.